# PC makes beeps when XOR encrypting a string and saving it in a text file

Tags: c++, encryption, xor, beep

I use XOR to encrypt the options I write to a text file, and decrypt them when I read them in.

Below is the code for encrypting the options and writing them to the file:

```
Settings settings;
const char key = 'x';

std::stringstream ss;
std::string original = "";
std::string encrypted = "";
std::ofstream file("./data/options.txt");

if (file.good()) {
  file.clear();

  // Build options string
  ss << "limitfps=" << (settings.getLimitFramerate() ? "1" : "0") << std::endl;
  ss << "fps=" << settings.getFramerateLimit();
  // etc...

  // Encrypt
  original = ss.str();
  for (std::size_t temp = 0; temp < original.size(); ++temp) {
    encrypted += original[temp] ^ (static_cast<int>(key) + temp) % 255;
  }

  // Print and write to file
  std::cout << "Saving encrypted data to file:\n" << encrypted << std::endl;
  file << encrypted;
  file.close();
}
```

Everything works but my PC makes 3 beeps for some reason. How do I make it not make the beeps?

And since it is in the code, another question: I don't need the `file.close()` at the end, right? I read that `close()` is automatically called when the end of the scope is reached?

Thanks

Comment: About the second question: yes, you're right, when the application leaves a scope, destructor of all variables (with desctructor) is called and that closes the file in your case. This includes thrown exceptions (which is why mutex locks can be (and are) used), but excludes crashes, termination (including termination of a thread) and other techniques of forcing application to be closed. Like power-off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`encrypted` will contain non-printable characters, so when you print them to the console, you'll get some garbage sent to the console.

Some of that garbage is apparently the ASCII code `0x07`/`^G`/`BEL`, which causes the console to beep.

To fix the problem either don't print `encrypted`, or print it in such a way that non-printable characters get filtered out or formatted as hexadecimal or something.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your encrypted string, that you pipe to the standard output, contains three times the character 0x07, alias "Bell".